# how to create checkered background with canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, background

I am having trouble making a checkered canvas background. The screen presently displays a solid color filling the whole screen.  This color is the fillStyle in the `else` statement under the two `for` loops. Am I using the modulus operator wrong? or is it something else?

```
function createBackground(){
        if(!Modernizr.canvas) return;

        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
            context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
            background = $('#game .background')[0],
            rect = background.getBoundingClientRect(), //returns the dimension of background
            gradient,
            monsterSize = monstr.settings.monsterSize;

        canvas.width = rect.width;
        canvas.height = rect.height;
        context.scale(rect.width, rect.height);

        /* create checker */
        cols = canvas.width / monsterSize;
        rows = canvas.height / monsterSize;

        console.log(cols); //8
        console.log(rows); //12
        console.log(monsterSize); //40
        for (var i=0; i<cols; i++){
            for (var j=0; j<rows; j++){
                if((i+j)% 2){ /* for every other block */
                    context.fillStyle = '#262626';
                    context.fillRect(i*monsterSize, j*monsterSize, monsterSize, monsterSize);
                } else {
                    context.fillStyle = '#E8E8E8';
                    context.fillRect(i*monsterSize, j*monsterSize, monsterSize, monsterSize);
                }
            };
        };

        /* add canvas to html element */
        background.appendChild(canvas); 
    }**
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are scaling the canvas wrong, making every tile on the checkerboard so big, that you can only see a single tile on the screen.

Comment this line out:

```
context.scale(rect.width, rect.height);
```

Or try replacing the values you pass with smaller numbers like `1`, `2`, etc, depending on the the amount of scaling you want - if you even need scaling.

See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Db7Jt/).